# Spotfire Cross Table Colours

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-analyst

I am looking to colour the column and row headers of a cross table in Spotfire. Currently Spotfire doesn't allow this, but wanted to check if this was possible through CSS/HTML?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually in the 11.0 version of Spotfire but it is not intuitive.  https://docs.spotfire.cloud.tibco.com/spotfire/GUID-D1F9470F-603B-454D-A21E-C2A4F189F14D.html gives a little bit of how this is accomplished.   It actually came out in 10.10 I believe.   If that isn't robust enough for you then you can also use the new mods introduced in 11.0 and I would recommend that over using CSS/HTML because while that can be done you are at the mercy of updates which could destroy what you have at any time since it is considered an unsupported feature.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JS snippet that you can use to Color the Headers :

```
function ColorHeaders() {
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("sfc-column-header");
    var slides2 = document.getElementsByClassName("sfc-row-header");
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        x = slides[i].firstChild.innerHTML
        //console.log(x)
        if (x == 'Item0') {
            slides[i].style.background = "Black";
        } else if (x == 'Item1') {
            slides[i].style.background = "Green";
        } else if (x == 'Item2') {
            slides[i].style.background = "Yellow";
        } else if (x == 'Item3') {
            slides[i].style.background = "Blue";
        } else if (x == 'Item4') {
            slides[i].style.background = "Red";
        } else if (x == 'Item5') {
            slides[i].style.background = "Purple";
        } else if (x == 'Item6') {
            slides[i].style.background = "Orange";
        } else {
            slides[i].style.background = "white";
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < slides2.length; i++) {
        x = slides2[i].firstChild.innerHTML
        //console.log(x)
        if (x == 'Item1') {
            slides2[i].style.background = "Black";
        } else if (x == 'Item2') {
            slides2[i].style.background = "Green";
        } else if (x == 'Item3') {
            slides2[i].style.background = "Yellow";
        } else if (x == 'Item4') {
            slides2[i].style.background = "Blue";
        } else if (x == 'Item5') {
            slides2[i].style.background = "Red";
        } else if (x == 'Item6') {
            slides2[i].style.background = "Purple";
        } else if (x == 'Item7') {
            slides2[i].style.background = "Orange";
        } else {
            slides2[i].style.background = "white";
        }
    }
}
var timer = setInterval(ColorHeaders, 1000);
```